# iOS - When trying to read bundle.man.url doesn't return anything

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, geojson, geo

I'm trying to add a `boundary` from my `geoJSON` file, I'm using the [GEOSwift](https://github.com/andreacremaschi/GEOSwift) pod. But when I run the project it always print the *"Unable to load geoJSON data, could not find such file."* message, which means something went wrong.

P.S the `geoJSON` file can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreacremaschi/GEOSwift/master/GEOSwiftPlayground/GEOSwift.playground/Resources/multipolygon.geojson). And I'm using swift 3.

```
func addBoundry() {
        print("1")
        if let geoJSONURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "multipolygon", withExtension: "geojson") {
            print("2")
            do {
                print("3")
                let geometries = try Geometry.fromGeoJSON(geoJSONURL)
                if let geo = geometries?[0] as? MultiPolygon {
                    print("4")

                    if let shapesCollection = geo.mapShape() as? MKShapesCollection {
                        print("5")

                        let shapes = shapesCollection.shapes

                        for shape in shapes {
                            print("6")
                            if let polygon = shape as? MKPolygon {
                                print("7")
                                mapView.add(polygon)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Unable to load geojson data")
            }
        } else {
            print("Unable to load geojson data, could not find such file.")
        }
    }
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Is the "multipolygon.geojson" file a part of your build target?

Comment: It is pasted into the project, but thats all. What do you mean by 'part of the build target'?

Comment: Select the file and make sure the target you're building is checked in the Identity Inspector (right column of Xcode, little page icon on top) under "Target Membership". It should also be listed in your target's build phases (select your project in the navigator, then the relevant target in the main pane, then "Build Phases" on the top), under "Copy Bundle Resources".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure "multipolygon.geojson" file is a part of your build target.

Select the file and make sure the target you're building is checked in the Identity Inspector (right column of Xcode, little page icon on top) under "Target Membership". It should also be listed in your target's build phases (select your project in the navigator, then the relevant target in the main pane, then "Build Phases" on the top), under "Copy Bundle Resources".

Comment: I have another geoJSON file containing property boundaries in a town. In the geoJSON file the coordinates is [97973.4655999987,6219081.53249992,0] when it should be  56.091648, 12.664262, 0 in the real world.

Is it possible to translate the coordinates from the geoJSON file to the real-world coordinates? And why aren't they the same?